# cpu overheating when watching youtube videos

Tags: google-chrome, cpu, youtube, overheating

i run fedora 29 on amd athlon ii x2 240 with 4gb ram. today suddenly cpu started overheating and shutting down while watching youtube videos. i'm not sure is problem with os, browser (google chrome) or something else. last os update i ran 3 days ago and it started happening today. sorry for poor information but i have no idea why is this happening so i don't know which information is relevant. if you need some information please ask and i will post it.

Answer (score 0):

It probably codec that was updated and uses CPU in different way. If in earlier versions CPU wasn't that hot probably codec was simpler or less demanding. Although it's bit surprising that graphic card doesn't take any role in decoding content.